# IIS Application is unable to connect to SQL Server database but works when testing in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

My web app is supposed to be a drop down menu that connects to my SQL Server database and gives me list of choices. When running it through Visual Studio, everything works fine. A list of choices is shown after clicking on the drop down menu.

However after publishing it to IIS, the drop down menu appears blank. I've tried adding `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`user in the SQL Server database. And setting the application pool identity to `NETWORK SERVICE` as well but it still doesn't work. I also made sure that the IIS and the application pool has proper access to the SQL database, and pretty much whatever solution I can google but nothing seems to work.

This is the connection string in my `web.config`, I've changed the actual names of the databases and password for security sake.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="Database1" 
             connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Catalog1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->

    <!--<add name="Database1" 
             connectionString="Data Source=MyBD;Initial Catalog=Catalog1;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add name="Database2" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MyBD;Initial Catalog=Catalog2;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Database3" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MyBD;Initial Catalog=Catalog3;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="Database1" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MyBD;Initial Catalog=Catalog1;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Database2" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MyBD;Initial Catalog=Catalog2;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Database3" 
         connectionString="Data Source=MyBD;Initial Catalog=Catalog3;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm not sure if it's a problem with my connection strings, or that I'm not publishing the website properly.

Comment: Which connectionString are you using? On the server, so you have more than one connectionString defined with Database2 and Database3? What error message are you getting? Can you get to MyBD and MyBD-DEV using SQL Server Studio locally? From the server?

Comment: I am actually using all connectionString, each database cross-reference each other to find a specific item. Sorry I don't know how to explain more of it. And the thing is, I don't get any error messages so I can't pinpoint what the problem is. And sorry, MyBD-Dev is actually supposed to be MyBD but I forgot to correct it on here. And yes, I am able to connect to my BD using SSMS locally and on my server.

Comment: There's an error message somewhere. Or there is confirmation that your query ran correctly and returned nothing. Do other database queries work? You need to post the code that populates your drop down in order to get help